# Topology question - Hypothetical - From Face to face via curve from center point - Possible

Tags: modeling

TopMod:

[Twisted Cube Handles](https://youtu.be/8tgZE6c-WhM)

does this kind of thing. Pick a face, pick another face and it easily, mostly connects the two faces together.  In Blender, this is more problematic.  I'm wondering would it be possible to, for example, poke faces - to get a center point, vertex, run a curve from the center vertex of one face to the center of another, then extrude a face from one curve point to the other, connecting the two faces.  Seems to me this would also allow for some interesting effects via twist, for example and accomplish something I haven't seen readily possible or demonstrated using Blender.

Conceptually, it seems like it would be possible.

Yes?  Would make for a nice addon I think done well adding additional topological functionality.

Comment: You’ve tried “Bridge Edge Loops”?

Comment: There are at least two tools I'm aware of that work comparably to what I have in mind.  They're both addons - paid.  One is Angle Tools.  It works by selecting connecting edges.  The last edge being the pivot edge.  Then select the process, curves or not, the number of cuts and the angle and offset.  There's Bend Face which works vcomparably but begins with faces and allows a greater degree of flexibility in choosing the pivot point.

Comment: Angle Tool: https://blendermarket.com/products/angle-tool

Bend Face: https://blendermarket.com/products/bend-face

Neither of them twists or connects easily other than connecting faces sharing a common edge.  Topmod was highly functional and versatile by comparison.  Bridge edge loops, I use, and, it has its uses, but, is equally limited in function.